# Dynamic Annotations in Indesign

Tags: dynamic, annotations, adobe-indesign

I'm creating a technical document in inDesign that requires annotations. Right now I've constructed my annotations by grouping a text box with an arrow head line segment. The problem is if I want to re-position the text box I have to re-angle / re-scale / re-position the line segment. Is there anyway to attach the line segment to the text box so it "sticks" to it as I move the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to use [anchored objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/indesign/user-guide.html/in/indesign/using/anchored-objects.ug.html) to achieve this.